# LPCSTR to LPCWSTR converting

Tags: lpcwstr, lpcstr

I have created implemetation of converting `LPCSTR` to `LPCWSTR`

```
LPSTR W2S(LPCWSTR str)
{
    LPSTR strTo;
    char* szTo = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, lstrlenW(str) + 1);
    szTo[lstrlenW(str)] = '\0';
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, str, -1, szTo, lstrlenW(str), NULL, NULL);
    strTo = szTo;
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, szTo);
    return strTo;
}
```

But it doesn't work, what's the problem?

Comment: `HeapFree(szTo)` and after this `return szTo`. only this is enough. already not say about other things

Comment: fixed, but still not working

Comment: of course. because too many errors. `WideCharToMultiByte` will fail with too small buffer error. many other errors

Comment: Could you help me?